# Why the trained neural network output the same results for each row in the last layer?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a graph neural network using pytorch, but the problem is the final output contain the same values for each row,  here is the  layer of my network

```py
self.linear_pre = nn.Linear(input_dim, feature_dim)  # (transform features)
self.linear_hidden = nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)  # -get different result
self.act = nn.ReLU()  # -get different result
self.linear_out_ = nn.Linear(output_dim, 1)  # same results for each row, example output is shown below
```

[image]
currently I am using one hot encoding as features for each graph, Adam optimizer, and weight initialization using xavier_uniform

I tried to change the learning rate, use random features, use scheduler still the problem persist

What else should I do? Any idea will be much appreciated

Comment: i see that self.linear_out_ has 1 output ...and how come you are getting such long tensor

Comment: helo @PrajotKuvalekar, i am gettingthis output after reshape out_position = self.linear_out(messages).squeeze(-1)

Comment: "the shape of features before anything is  torch.Size([400, 32])", then i reshaped these features using this command   features = "features.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, features.shape[1], 1)", then i passed this shape to relu, and get this output 'features after reshape torch.Size([400, 32, 32])', which is the input to 'self.linear_out' is there anything wrong @PrajotKuvalekar

Comment: can you elaborate more on your question...can u post whole code? @christinamuro